# How can I run an 'R' script without suppressing output?

Tags: r

At the moment I have a very simple script.  If I type the commands into a console, I have text printing to the screen.  However if I run the script using the following

```
source('myscript.R')
```

The contents are executed but nothing is printed to the screen. How do I stop console output from being suppressed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IMHO you need to specify `print.eval` parameter set to `TRUE` if you want to get only the output (and not the commands). If you would need the commands too, you should set `echo` to `TRUE` (which implies setting `print.eval` to `TRUE`).

For example:

`source('myscript.R', print.eval  = TRUE)`

Answer (score -1):

Use
sink() to bring back the r console output as normal