# How can I get the output of the summary() command if it is called within a loop?

Tags: r

Suppose `Z` is a vector of feature names.

How can I get the summary command in the following Rscript to actually print?

```
for (var in Z)                
{                             
#cat(i)                       
form = paste('crim ~', var)   
lm.fit=lm(form, data=Boston)  
summary(lm.fit)               
}
```

If I type `summary(lm.fit)` at the R prompt, it works, but when I source the Rscript which contains this loop, I get no output. I have already tried the solution [How can I run an 'R' script without suppressing output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959337/how-can-i-run-an-r-script-without-suppressing-output) but it does not cause summary to print.

Comment: `print(summary(lm.fit))`?

Comment: or `show(summary(lm.fit))`

Comment: This is FAQ 7.16, at least the answer to that FAQ is the same as the answer to this question, though the title to the FAQ only talks about sourcing, so it would be easy to miss that it applies to loops as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`summary()` is supposed to return a object of class `"summary.foo"` assuming that the `summary.foo()` method was called. Then a `print()` method for that class, `print.summary.foo()` is supposed to print the object returned by `summary.foo()`.

Automatic printing is turned off in `for ()` loops (and some other circumstances. You need an explicit call to `print()`. When you call `summary(bar)` at the prompt, you are effectively doing `print(summary(bar))`. It is that addition of the `print()` call that is suppressed in `for ()` loops.

Hence, write

```
print(summary(lm.fit))
```

in your loop and you'll see the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of `for loop` using `lapply`.

```
z<-as.list(c("disp","cyl"))
nn<-lapply(z,function(x) summary(lm(as.formula(paste("mpg",x,sep="~")),data=mtcars)))
print(nn) # or show(nn)
```

If you want to stick to `for loop` here is the solution:

```
for (i in z){

    k[[i]]<-summary(lm(as.formula(paste("mpg",z[i],sep="~")),data=mtcars))
    print(k[[i]])
}
```

Comment: I didn't think `lapply` would print results when called in an Rscript session. (I checked to see if `Rscript -e 'z<-as.list(c("disp","cyl"))
lapply(z,function(x) summary(lm(as.formula(paste("mpg",x,sep="~")),data=mtcars)))'` would return what one sees in an interactive session and it didn't.

Comment: What type of object would you initialise k as prior to starting the loop in order to store lm() summaries in k?