# RStudio not displaying any output

Tags: r, rstudio

When I write a script in RStudio, and run it, it isn't displaying any output. However, if I run the commands directly in console, it's working.

For example, if I have a file called script1.R which has the following code:

```
r = 5 * 25 * 2
r
```

When I do

```
source('~/Desktop/script1.R')
```

nothing happens. However, if I just type those two lines into console, it's working fine. What can I do to fix this? I have RStudio Version 0.98.1103 and R 3.1.2.

Comment: Use `print(r)` in the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959337/how-can-i-run-an-r-script-without-suppressing-output there are several arguments to `?source` which may fit what you need: print.eval, echo, verbose

Comment: Thanks, using print.eval = TRUE worked. It always worked without specifying this argument, but for some reason, it suddenly stopped working today.

Comment: Interesting -- maybe there's some special RStudio thing that was going on. Glad this fix worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like `View(r)`. Or like Alexey said `print(r)`.

Also, I would say that it is "bad practice" to use something like `r` as a variable name. Try something more specific.